# Neural network for approximating a function with four parameters

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I have a function that looks like this:

```
y = a^(2b) + c^(2d)
```

I would like to approximate this function by training a neural network using backpropagation. The range of the variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` is currently indeterminate to me, so to begin with I assume that they are all in the range [0, 1]. Then I generate a training set by assuming a uniform distribution on the variables. After finding the right amount of hidden nodes and layers as well as good values of backpropagation's learning rate and momentum, I can reach a low average error on a test set using this range. However, as soon as I change the range of the variables to something like [-1, 1], the error increases a lot.

Is it normal that I need to change the structure of the neural network (see coment below) and the parameters of backpropagation depending on the range of the variables I feed to the network? Or may this have something to do with the nodes in the hidden layer having a sigmoid activation function?

Note: When the range of a variable is not [0, 1], I normalize it to that range so it will work with the sigmoid function. Also note that the function may not be `y` is not necessary for answering the question, but gives some context.

Comment: The function value [changes dramatically](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20a%5E%282b%29%2C%20a%20from%20-1%20to%201%2C%20b%20from%20-1%20to%201) with the change of the sign...

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk So you believe that the whole structure of the network needs to change?

Comment: And what is the current structure? Maybe you can show the code?

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk Unfortunately I cannot show the code at the moment, but just to clarify: what I mean by the structure of the network is the number of hidden layers, the number of nodes in each layer and the activation function for each node. So my question here is if it is normal in general that this structure needs to be changed depending on the range of the parameters fed to the network (independent of the actual problem or the function that is to be approximated). My guess is yes, but I would like just to have that confirmed for the record.

Answer (score 0):

Are the nodes in your output layer also sigmoid? Because if so then they never will be able to replicate your input function: for negative values of  `b` and `d`, `y` approaches infinity as `a` and `c` approach zero.

Just riffing off some possible things you could try, I'm definitely not an expert so take all this advice with a grain of salt:

- Change your definition of "Average Error"? You could try using
  something like "median root squared error" to allow for occasional large errors
- Change your range of your variables to `a, c in [-1, -epsilon] union [epsilon, 1]` for some `epsilon >0` so that your function is bounded.
- Change your output nodes to use an unbounded activation function, [it looks like this **may** be a theoretically OK thing to do](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/aans/2012/571358/) ... you could let your output nodes have the activation function `y = a^(2b) + c^(2d)` for example but maybe this would be cheating ;)